# store value into an array JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I would like to store some values into an array in HTML. The values are from a random number generator in Python as {{player.a1s1}}. This has been taken care of. basically, when on each click on button "mm1a" , the player will see one more button in the form. the number of clicks will be recorded. and I would like to have the random number {{player.a1s1}} shown on the button to be stored in JS as an array. My code could not store the value into array.

HTML

```
<div class="container1">
<p>
    {{ player.text1a }} # this will get the text from a python variable.
</p>

<form id="frm1">
<button  class="toAdd">{{player.a1s1}}</button>
<button  class="toAdd">{{player.a1s1}}</button>
<button  class="toAdd">{{player.a1s1}}</button>
<button  class="toAdd">{{player.a1s1}}</button>
<button  class="toAdd">{{player.a1s1}}</button>
<button  class="toAdd">{{player.a1s1}}</button>
</form>
</div>

<div><button class="mm1a" type="button">{{ player.optiona1 }}</button>
# this will get the innerhtml from another python variable.

</div>

<p>
  samplemma1<input id="id_samplemma1" name="samplemma1" value="0"></input>
</p>
```

in javascript

```
$('.mm1a').on('click',function(){
$('.toAdd:eq('+count+')').show();
count++;
hello();
getarraya();
});

var clicks = 0; # to count how many clickes the players did
function hello() {
    clicks += 1;
    document.getElementById("id_clicksmma1").innerHTML = clicks;
    document.getElementById("id_clicksmma1").value = clicks;
};

# below part does not work
var myarraya = [];
var c = 0;
function getarraya() {
    c += 1;
    myarraya.push(document.forms["frm1"].elements[c].innerHTML);
    document.getElementById("id_clicksmma1").innerHTML = myarraya;
    document.getElementById("id_clicksmma1").value = myarraya;
};
```

Comment: I see. how can I get the whole array as a string? that is what I would like to do

Comment: var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.toString();

Answer (score 0):

jquery "on" must be inside document.ready and variable myarraya 
and  c  move it to top.